# Orace 11g : Create table in another schema with only select permission to schema owner

Tags: oracle, select, oracle11g, privileges

I have 2 users: User1 and User2

I am able to create table in schema of User2 from User1

```
create table user2.tmp_tab (
     temp1 varchar2(20),
     temp2 varchar2(20)
);
Table created Successfully
```

but I want **User2** to have **only select** privileges on the table.
and also I don't want to create table in Schema User1.

Is it possible ? How can it be done ?

Comment: The schema owner will have all the privileges on his schema objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can't. The schema **owner** automatically has **all object privileges** for his own schema.

From [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/html/A96524_01/c24privs.htm),

> A user automatically has all object privileges for schema objects
>   contained in his or her schema. A user can grant any object privilege
>   on any schema object he or she owns to any other user or role.

Comment: Thanks for the documentation ink

Comment: @user2019331 You're welcome. Please mark it answered if it solved your issue.

Comment: can i revoke all the privileges  from User1 (user created the table) in User2 schema have it on1y with User2(owner).

Comment: If you want user1 not to have any privilege in user2, then revoke all privileges of user1 from user2. You cannot revoke any privilege of the schema owner.